# how to create dynamic link list like on ebay all catergories page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I was hoping someone could post an example how to create a dynamic link list like on the ebay all categories page showns here :

http://www.ebay.com/sch/allcategories/all-categories

When you click on "more" the selected list grows and when "fewer" is clicked it goes back

thanks for your input in advance

Comment: The links are there when the page is rendered.  They are just in a hidden div.  When you click more/less it toggles the div from hidden to visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.toggle()` method.  Just set a class on your items that you would normally hide so you can easily select them.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/